# Location Challenging Matching API Facebook

Tags: facebook, foursquare

I have a challenging location matching API problem and would really appreciate if any [Facebook](http://ukproperty.management/) & Foursquare API expert here can help? How do one match a particular place in Facebook Graph API to the place in Foursquare Venue API? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Note** : Very open and lazy question, but hey, I was personally interested and challenged by the question.

If you access both API's you can match a location of a Facebook Page to a FourSquare Venue based on

> longitude, latitude, zip, city, and so on.

There will be always a possibility that the matching does not succeed.

**BUT**

The main question is, how will you select your data that needs to be matched ?

- You can search via the Facebook API for a Facebook Page with a location on a specific area based on longitude, latitude and diameter.
- You can search via the FourSquare on the Venue endpoint also based on longitude, latitude and more.

**SO**

if you have a specific Venue that needs to be matched to a specific Facebook location and you have on of the two to start of with. You are able to match. (So you have specific Foursquare venue, now I want to match it to Facebook Page, or other way around)

**Back to the question**

- It is theoretically possible
- You can implement it by using the following endpoints :

  - Facebook : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#search
  - FourSquare : https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search
- Always good to make a proof of concept still as extra verification